# Combining SUMIF with VLOOKUP or IndexMatch

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to compare the values of Column A elements against its mapped equivalent in Column D. See the mapping table in `Range I:J`

The first one is easy, in Column D, `211010` has a value of 9,570 so does its mapped equivalent (`B1001)`in column A, so difference is zero.

However, the next element `222010` is mapped to two elements `B30` and `B3030`

What I want is a formula in column Zthat adds up values of elements in column  D; for example `222010` which is -3,041 and compares it to the sum of its mapped equivalent in column A (B30 & B3030) which is (-6327+3286) also 3,041 and returns the difference which may be zero or otherwise.

I tried using combining SUMIF/+IndexMatch/VLOOKUP but I couldn't get it to work for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first part with a simple `SUMIF`, i.e.

`=SUMIF(D$2:D$17,D2,E$2:E$17)`

and then the latter with this "array formula"

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$2:A$17,IF(I$2:I$17=D2,H$2:H$17),0)),B$2:B$17))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You can simply subtract one from the other for your comparison